# Como iniciar a janela em tela cheia com tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fullscreen

```
from caixaimport import *

# Variables



# Tkinter Variables

win_width, win_height = 1280, 1024

windows = Tk() # start a variable Tk
windows.geometry(f'{win_width}x{win_height}')
windows.title('SCH payment system') # putting a title in variable window




# Method



# Program

windows.mainloop() # Start the variable "window" with the function mainloop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
windows.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
```

PS: Eu utilizei essa solução para resolver esse problema; quando procurei, fiz a busca em inglês e encontrei a seguinte thread [Python 3.3 Tkinter Fullscreen](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.python/c/WJr_vNByTU0)

Comment: Pode colocar alguma documentação ou explicação? E em que ponto ele deve fazer isso?

Comment: Adicionei o link que utilizei como referência na época da minha solução.

Comment: Já ajudou, obrigado e valeu

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *
        
janela = Tk()
janela.configure(bg='light blue1')
janela.title('tela cheia')
janela.overrideredirect(True)
janela.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(janela.winfo_screenwidth(), janela.winfo_screenheight()))

def sair():
    janela.destroy()

def maxmize():
    janela.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(janela.winfo_screenwidth(), janela.winfo_screenheight()))
    janela.overrideredirect(True)

def abas():
    janela.overrideredirect(False)

bt = Button(width=20, bg='red',font='roboto',text='fechar janela',command=sair)
bt.place(x=0,y=0)

bt = Button(width=20, bg='light blue',font='roboto',text='mostrar como tela cheia',command=maxmize)
bt.place(x=190,y=0)

bt = Button(width=20, bg='light blue',font='roboto',text='mostrar como janela',command=abas)
bt.place(x=380,y=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Dá para usar:

```
windows.state('zoomed')
```